# why HttpEventType.UploadProgress event executeonly one time in Angular file upload request?

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

I am trying to upload files from angular. and I wanted to show the upload progress also.

**upload.service.ts**

```
public uploadProductImage(obj: FormData, id: string) {
    return this._http.post(baseUrl + `/product/upload`, obj, {
      headers: {
        product_id: id,
      },
      reportProgress : true,
      observe : 'events'
    });
  }
```

**upload.component.ts**

```
uploadClick() {
    const fd = new FormData();

    // for(const f of this.file_url) {
    //   fd.append('image', f.file, f.file.name);
    // }
    fd.append('image', this.file_url[0].file, this.file_url[0].file.name);
    this.service.uploadProductImage(fd, this.product_id.toString())
      .subscribe(
        event => {
          if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            console.log(event.loaded, event.total);
            this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);

          } else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
            console.log(event.body);
            this.file_url = [];
          }

        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }
```

Now image uploading is working. only progress bar is not working. I am getting one event with `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` immediately and `event.loaded` and `event.total` both are equal.

so progressbar directly become `100` but to complete the request it take some time.

Comment: Having the very same issue, any help is appreciated

Comment: Same here, what would be the proposed solution? OP did find it?

Comment: @DARKGuy see my answer. Msy be you can find this useful

Comment: @RonaldKorze see my answer. Msy be you can find this useful

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. For me the server is on localhost and because of that the upload was instantaneously and the progress was always 100%.
Try to throttle the request in Chrome and you will see some other progress percents before the upload is completed.

---

The steps how to throttle the network in Chrome:

1. Open DevTools (F12)
2. Click the 'Network' tab
3. Select which type of connection you want to imitate ('Slow 3G' will do the trick)

Comment: How is this even a fix to the above question? The progress bar must be updated without modifying the throttle settings.

Comment: There is no fix for the question, because the code in the question works fine on a deployed web application. The issue with the percentage of the progress bar occured (for me) because both the web api and the angular project runs on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

I am Using this one in a new project. and it's working. Hope it will help you

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpEventType, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';


uploadMethod() {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.selectedFile);

        const req = new HttpRequest('POST', apiEndpoint, formData, {
          reportProgress: true,
        });

        this.http.request(req)
        .subscribe(
          (event) => {
            if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              // This is an upload progress event. Compute and show the % done:
              this.percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
              console.log(`File is ${this.percentDone}% uploaded.`);
            } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              console.log('File is completely uploaded!');
              console.log(event.body);
            }
          },
          err => console.error(err)
        );
}
```

Comment: please explain what you have done differently than the original question. Pasting only the code that works for you isn't a good answer.

Comment: @NiamatullahBakhshi its my question and nobody has posted a good answer. If u have any answer to this please post it. I am just trying to help others. I created a new HttpRequest instance then subscribing it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and in my case the cause was a custom `HttpInterceptor` where I used `toPromise`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    return from(this.handle(req, next));
}

private async handle(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  try {
      return await next.handle(req).toPromise();
  } catch (err: any) {
      // error-handling logic
  }
}
```

After changing above code to:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        // error-handling logic
        return throwError(err);
      }));
  }
```

the issue was resolved.