# Angular HttpClient observe events don't return type 1

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular Frontend that should upload data to my NodeJS Express Backend.

On the Angular side, I use the HttpClientModule:

```
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
const http = this.http.post('https://example.api.com', formData, { observe: 'events', reportProgress: true }) as Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
http.subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log(response);
  ... do other things like displaying the progress
});
```

On the NodeJS side, I use Formidable to process the data:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  var form = new IncomingForm();
  form.parse(req);
  form.on('fileBegin', (name, file) => {
    ... save the file
  });
  ...
  form.on('end', (field, file) => {
    ... do some db entries
    res.status(200).json(...);
  }
}
```

This is a very high-level breakdown of my code.

The issue is that I don't receive any progressEvents of type 1 (HttpEventType.UploadProgress) on my production server. On localhost, everything works fine.
But once it is deployed, I just receive the following events (printed by console.log):

> {type: 0}
>
> {type: 3, loaded: 26, total: 26}

Which I get on localhost, but not on production:

> {type: 1, loaded: 54116352, total: 172122161}

The Server has an NGINX Reverse Proxy to schedule the request.

The Applications are provided by Docker. Angular uses Nginx:alpine and NodeJS uses Node:14.

I tried so many things so that I can't list them all. I would be very grateful for every hint.

Comment: you can try requesting from slow 3g connection from chrome dev tools, and check now type 1 response coming back or not ? may be you can not get uploadProgress event because of fast request finished.

Comment: i already tried to upload big files and it took a couple of minutes until I get a type 3 event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998184/why-httpeventtype-uploadprogress-event-executeonly-one-time-in-angular-file-uplo check this out if itw working for you or not/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and in my case the cause was a custom `HttpInterceptor` where I used `toPromise`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    return from(this.handle(req, next));
}

private async handle(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  try {
      return await next.handle(req).toPromise();
  } catch (err: any) {
      // error-handling logic
  }
}
```

After changing above code to:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler){
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(catchError(err => {
        // error-handling logic
        return throwError(err);
      }));
  }
```

the issue was resolved.